# NestJS Logging into File, Database, etc using either default logger or npm like winston

Tags: node.js, logging, nestjs, winston

NestJS implemented with default logger. It send the output to console.

May I know, How to configure the default logger to send the output to file, database.

In addition,

if I want to use Winston in NestJS, how to use/inject/extend with various transport option.

It should not be tighly coupled with NestJS and always able to replace with some other logger.

Answer (score 33):

You cannot configure the default logger to send the output somewhere else.
You need to create a custom logger or better: Extend the default logger to implement your needs.

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

export class MyLogger extends Logger {
  error(message: string, trace: string) {
    // write the message to a file, send it to the database or do anything
    super.error(message, trace);
  }
}
```

Read [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#extend-built-in-logger) to see how to implement this.

But if you want to use Winston anyway there is no need to reinvent the wheel, you can use the the awesome npm package [nest-winston](https://github.com/gremo/nest-winston).

First you need to register the `WinstonModule` in your `app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WinstonModule } from 'nest-winston';
import * as winston from 'winston';
[...]

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig),
    WinstonModule.forRoot({
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
      ],
    }),
    SearchesModule,
    SuggestionsModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then you can inject and use the logger anywhere like this:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Logger } from 'winston';
import { SuggestionsRepository } from './suggestions.repository';

@Injectable()
export class SuggestionsService {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(SuggestionsRepository)
    private repository: SuggestionsRepository,
    @Inject('winston')
    private readonly logger: Logger,
  ) { }

  getAllSuggestions = async () => {
    this.logger.info('Returning suggestions...');
    return await this.repository.getAll();
  }
}
```

Read the [documentation](https://github.com/gremo/nest-winston/blob/master/README.md) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer and implementation example! Very helpful.

Comment: this is cool but as a solution it clutters up code quite a bit having to inject that into all constructors where you intend using it -- as well as calling this. requires refactoring all existing code significantly.

Comment: @SebastianG what can be the solution for that?

Comment: your example has too many unrelated codes.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to implement logging result at files

```
 WinstonModule.forRoot({
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        winston.format.json(),
      ),
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.File({
          dirname: path.join(__dirname, './../log/debug/'), //path to where save loggin result 
          filename: 'debug.log', //name of file where will be saved logging result
          level: 'debug',
        }),
        new winston.transports.File({
          dirname: path.join(__dirname, './../log/info/'),
          filename: 'info.log',
          level: 'info',
        }),
      ],
    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can simply pipe the stdout to a file:
npm run start > app.log

in Powershell you can use Out-File
probably like this (not a powershell expert though)
npm run start | Out-File -filepath app.log

So logger libs also support direct file output handling within your app code.

Comment: If you do it this way, how will you rotate files on a daily basis?

Comment: plus the output file does not convert those indentation to spaces properly